# Benefit of using WITH (TABLOCK, XLOCK) when inserting one line in a table?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I found in some legacy code (originally SQLServer 2008) `INSERT` hints that I'm not sure to understand.

I have a table (storing many rows) and some procedures to fill this table.
We insert rows one by one. One procedure call = one line inserted.
Fine.

Sometimes (not always) SQL code looks like:

```
insert into my_table with(tablock, xlock)
values(......)
```

Why [tablock / xlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) have been put here ?

What could be the benefit of locking a table when we insert only **one** line ?

Note this insert is embedded within a transaction with isolation **serializable**.

(I can imagine the benefit if we want to [insert a bunch of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165659/benefits-of-using-with-tablock-on-an-insert), ie. better performance).

Comment: Another reason to do this is to resolve a deadlock.  A simple remediation to resolve a deadlock lock _bigger_ and _earlier_.  You only get a deadlock when two sessions first acquire _compatible_ locks, then later attempt to acquire incompatible locks.  If you force one to acquire an _incompatible_ locks initially, no deadlock.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The deadlock story is interesting and I'll investigate this point carrefully. Thx for this idea!

Answer (score 1):

**Exclusive Access or Increased Performance**

From what I've seen, this "could be" someone's attempt to make sure that absolutely no one else enters identical rows, that you're inserting, into the table.

Or if it's mass inserts, it can save time and have minimal logging.

https://drillchina.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/use-tablock-to-boost-your-insert-into-select-performance/

Comment: as said in the question, this is not about mass insertion. We insert just *one* line.
And regarding inserting duplicates, I don't see how tablock could prevent that since a transaction isolation level is *serializable* (and actually, duplicates is not an issue in this use case).

Comment: Looks like the original question has changed to reflect your comments as well.

Comment: indeed, I added the *serializable* point.